# Is azure search cost depend on number hits?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-cognitive-search

I want to understand, how the azure search cost getting calculated. I am referring this link and as per my understanding the cost is getting calculated based on storage capacity, no. of indexes and partition.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/search/

Just need confirmation- is there any additional cost will be added based on number of hits. Suppose my azure search APIs (search, suggest, and autocomplete) will be 20000 times per day, is cost will increase. Currently I want to go with basic or standard tier.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Search pricing is based solely on the number of search units in your service and the pricing tier. It is not based on the level of usage of your search service, because that service is dedicated for your use.

> per my understanding the cost is getting calculated based on storage capacity

Note that search units are units of compute and storage resources, not just storage.

Comment: Thanks Bruce for the confirmation. Just one more thing so if I selected standard tier and there is mentioned the we can use it up to 36 unit per service. What is mean by this?

Comment: Good to know it's not based on number of hits/usage. Thanks for this again.

Comment: What is it about the 36 search unit limit that you don’t understand exactly?

Comment: Yes Bruce, I can see is scale out limit -Up to 36 units per service
(max 12 partitions; max 12 replicas). But if you explain more it'll be good.

Comment: I’m not sure what there is to explain that isn’t already in our documentation. If you have a specific question, I would be happy to answer it.